# I have SQLite db with 3 rows, when i delete data from row, data will lost but row will still, how can i delete that blank row?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I have xamarin app and I am using SQLite for saving data, if I have 3 rows and delete second row, then data will delete but row will be blank and its still here and problem is, that I need to load one column from every row. I am using for cycle and count to set maximum for it. But count says I have two rows so for cycle load just first and not second because second is on third line and second is blank.
I need to delete blank rows or to discover another solution how to load it. How can i delete blank DB?
Counting algorythm:

```
public int GetNumberPhotos()
    {            
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
        db.CreateTable<Airplane>();
        int count = 0;
        if (db.Table<Airplane>().FirstOrDefault(l => l.Id == 1) != null)
            count = db.Table<Airplane>().Count();
        
        return count;
    }
```

loading:

```
public int BetterUniReg()
    {
        int numberPhotos = GetNumberPhotos();
        string[] allReg = new string[numberPhotos];
        string[] uniReg = new string[numberPhotos];
        int uniRegCnt = 0;
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
        //db fill
        for (int i = 0; i <= numberPhotos; i++)
        {
            if (db.Table<Airplane>().FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == i) != null)
            {
                var rowData = db.Table<Airplane>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == i);                    
                i--;
                allReg[i] = rowData.Registration;
                i++;
            }                
        }
```

Here is delete code:

```
private async void deleteButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var action = await DisplayAlert("Delete", "Do you want delete picture?", "Cancel", "Delete");
        if (action)
        {                
        }   
        else
        {
            var butto = sender as Button;
            var frame = butto.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as Frame;
            await frame.FadeTo(0, 600);
            var button = (Button)sender;                
            var plane = (Airplane)button.BindingContext;                
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
            db.Delete<Airplane>(plane.Id);
            Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: when you delete data from your Data Base you need to reload data again, use your load metod BetterUniReg()

Comment: How can i Do that?

Comment: But how to reload that database?

Comment: BetterUniReg() in your case

Comment: ah like this, but this is not a problem, I am doing this

Comment: I need to delete blank rows in sqlite database

Comment: deleting a row should not create a blank row.  You have not shown any code that actually deletes a row, or demonstrated how this results is a "blank" row.

Comment: Question is updated @Jason

Comment: What makes you think that you have a blank row after the delete?

Comment: if i want first row it works 'var rowData = db.Table<Airplane>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == 1);' when i set 'var rowData = db.Table<Airplane>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == 2);' it is null and when i set 'var rowData = db.Table<Airplane>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == 3);' its not null problem is with second, thats why i think its empty @Jason

Comment: If you delete ID=2, then Query ID=2, OF COURSE it will return a null.  You are asking for a row you just deleted, so it will return nothing.  What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Ah, you have true, do you know how to load rows? For example row 1, then row 2...?

Comment: `db.Table<Airplane>()` will return ALL rows

Comment: And how can i select only one row then? Like this? 'db.Table<Airplane>(5)'

Comment: `db.Table<Airplane>(r => r.Id == 5);`

Comment: But I need first row no first id @Jason Is there any possible way?

Comment: there is no guarantee that the rows will be stored in any particular order.  You can try `db.Table<Airplane>().FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: That doesnt work, I was using this on start... Dont you know other way? My goal is to load one column into array. I need to work with it.

Comment: If your goal is to “load one column into an array” why are you asking about loading the “first row”?  It is very difficult to help when you are unable to describe the specific problem you are having.

Comment: I am asking how to load first line not first id and I want to load column with name Registrations from first line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done walkaround by adding if its last row and its null then do one more cycle.
Here is code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberPhotos; i++)
        {
            if (db.Table<Airplane>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == i) != null)
            {
                var rowData = db.Table<Airplane>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == i);
                allReg[regnumber] = rowData.Registration;
                regnumber++;
            }
            if (db.Table<Airplane>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == i) == null && i == numberPhotos)
            {
                numberPhotos = numberPhotos + 1;
            }
        }
```